# Using cloudflare stream api return multiple videos by UID with one request

Tags: api, stream, cloudflare

Working with the cloudflare stream api and I cannot seem to find any detail as to how to return multiple videos by UID. I can return one or I can return many seemingly at random.

Docs can be found here

https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/stream-videos-list-videos

I have tried adding a uid and id query parameter and it has no effect. I can also not find any information in the docs about how to do this.